# Что работает быстрее Map или Array?

Tags: java, android

Есть

```
Map<Integer,Picture> mPict = new HashMap<>();
```

и

```
Picture[] aPict = new Picture[100];
```

Что будет работать быстрее и насколько?

Как буду использовать: один раз заполню массив или карту, а потом буду обращаться к элементам. По одному или по порядку. Пересоздание массива или карты не планируется. При загрузке приложения заполню массив данными из файлов и все, буду их использовать, чтобы не обращаться постоянно к файлам.

Comment: Это смотря что Вы с ними делать будете.

Comment: На какой машине? какие объемы?) в какой стадии луна?

Comment: Они оба пустые и не работают. Вот когда будут работать тогда можно будет понять, что быстрее и вообще, можно ли их сравнивать.

Comment: ИМХО, быстрее будет работать int i = 0;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HashMap это структура данных позволяющая делать быстрый поиск по ключу. То есть поиск делается за константное количество операций O(1).

Если же вам надо найти элемент в массиве, то это делается через полный перебор элементов, то есть количество операций O(n).

Соответственно если у вас будет много операций поиска, то HashMap значительно быстрее.

Если речь идёт о добавлении элементов, то опять же HashMap работает быстрее так как массив полностью пересоздаётся при изменении числа элементов, да и вообще в него добавлять нельзя, он фиксированный по размеру.

Но это всё в случае большого количества элементов. При малом количестве элементов массив будет работать быстрее.

Места же HashMap занимает побольше, так как это сложная структура данных и для поддержания быстрого поиска в нём имеются скрытые дополнительные элементы, которые занимают память.

Конечно есть много разных ситуаций, и в каждой ситуации решение что применять лучше может быть своё, в этом посте я не буду описывать все варианты. А ваш вопрос не позволяет ответить более точно именно для вашего варианта, недостаточно данных.

[Почитать про Map.](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/02/11/9-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE-Map-%D0%B2-Java.html)

Comment: >>Если речь идёт о добавлении элементов, то опять же Map работает быстрее<< а так ли это?

Comment: @test123 при больших объёмах, думаю там добавление быстрее чем O(N), не могу точно сказать асимптотику, поищу в интернете сейчас.

Comment: поиск по мапе выполняется также за O(n)

Comment: @JVicВ статье по ссылке описана производительность, но можно и в других местах поискать. Там поиск на основе корзин сделать, buckets, можно поискать в интернете какая у этого алгоритма скорость работы.

Comment: Лично я подозреваю, что всё зависит от реализации Map. Согласитесь, SortedMap как бы намекает, что добавить в него элемент - не такая простая задача, как вы описываете.

Comment: Зачем в интернете искать? Если я и так знаю что в худшем случае это будет  O(n) Как и в масиве для поиска элемента необходимо бежать по всем до первого совпадения, сравнивая хэшмапу с массивом хешей.

Comment: @JVic в стандартном использовании для int-овых id-шников работает за константное время. Но да в худшем работает медленее, но и мой ответ не претендует на полноту, учитывая то что сам вопрос идёт без пояснений, как и писал в ответе вариантов может быть очень много.

Comment: @test123 согласен, зависит от реализации, я про обычную HashMap имел ввиду. Но всё же если добавлять в обычный массив скажем из 1000000 элементов, то там надо будет весь массив пересоздать. Хотя с другой стороны сравнивать вообще надо не с массивом а хотя бы с ArrayList, а там есть запас для добавления, и в результате добавляется намного быстрее  и это не требует пересоздания.

Comment: >>я про обычную HashMap имел ввиду.<< Нет, вы явно указали "Map", а это поведения десятка различных классов. HashMap - это всего лишь одна из многих реализаций.

Comment: Пересоздание/реалокация памяти есть и в массивах, и в картах и в других коллекциях. Map здесь не гарантирует того что вы описали. За это отвечает конкретная реализация.

Comment: @test123 Спасибо. Хорошо, исправляю.

Comment: Не сложная структура Макс 400 строк если память не изменяет, и поиск у вас будет О(n) также откроется массив, и обычным циклом и equals у вас будет искаться по хеш таблице. Если верить вашим словам , можно ваще все по битовые операции переписывать , зачем нам фиксированный размер , давай все в хешмапу быстрей будет. Мне нравится что люди плюсуют.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei ну я вообще на C# всегда почти Dictionary использую, а массив только в редких специальных случаях. Но как говорил выше логиченее сравнивать HashMap с ArrayList а не просто с массивом, так как массив это простой тип, примитив, а ArrayList полноценная коллекция. Коллекцию лучше сравнивать с коллекцией. Кстати вы можете написать свой ответ. Я написал как я понимаю, могу тоже не всё понимать. Возможно ваш ответ разъяснит ситуацию.